# Akka cluster brain crack

Tags: akka, cluster-computing

Description of the problem:
   In a 3-node cluster, all nodes monitor each other, when a connection between two nodes fails, the cluster divide into 3 cluster, every cluster have one node.

Example:
For example, In 3-node cluster, the default value of monitored-by-nr-of-members is 5, and enable the auto-down, assume the cluster nodes is 1-2-3, when the connection between 2 and 3 fails, 2 think 3 is unreachable, and 3 think is unreachable too. After a period of time, 1 remove the 2 and 3 from the cluster, because of the connection failure between 2 and 3, the cluster divide into three 1-node cluster eventually.

Answer (score 1):

A good read on the [split brain resolver](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/rp-16s01p05/scala/split-brain-resolver.html) problem, however:

> This is a feature of the Lightbend Reactive Platform that is
>   exclusively available for Lightbend Project Success Subscription
>   customers.